# If function arg is used as generic, TS will accept any prop in arg. How to restrict this?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a function where the keys of the object passed to it are used in the return type of the hook:

```
type MyOptions = {
  [key: `${number}${'s'|'ms'}`]: string
}

function useMyHook<O extends MyOptions>(options: O): MyReturnType<O> {
  // ...
}
```

When calling this function, typescript doesn't complain about invalid keys:

```
useMyHook({
  foo: 'bar'
})
```

Although if I define options like this,

```
const options: MyOptions = {
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

TypeScript will highlight invalid keys as expected.

How do I ensure correct typechecking of the function arguments?

[TS playground with code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBLAtsAYtLAQ3gF44ADAEgG8A7AVywCNgoBfGgIk7gB85OWAM49+nEW3IBuAFBIUcALKIA8mBgYItIXDIAlYAGNoAEwA8mHPihEYAGjiFaiAHwy5yVMoMx6UWmieZiouunDUbDIAZvS0hhpacPRCwMoAEhAQANbBcKAwwLQmOspqCdouABQQ6praAFxwKgCUjd7Avv6BKMGh1DJwcAD0Q3AAdBMDcFAdfrRwACwATDKRMsmpiBnZlf2DgyNwAO4AFohwtBB5UFDQOieswAD8U1GZjQDkTIRQH6vN7mM2ngNXKQjaqlqWh0ZD2cDeEE+31+qymQA)

Comment: You can check if the keys of `O` are assignable to the keys of `MyOptions`: https://tsplay.dev/NnEXqw Also, notice that the error messages emitted are identical.

Comment: TypeScript is doing "correct" typechecking; object types in TypeScript do not prohibit extra properties. [Excess property checking](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) only happens in object literals because the compiler will *forget* the keys, but no such forgetting happens with `O extends MyOptions`.  If you want to prohibit extra props in your generic, you can do so [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WkE5PN). Does that fully address the question? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @vr. & Jcalz thanks, your answers are what I was looking for!

Comment: I see @vr. got here first; do you want to write the answer here or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the keys of `O` are assignable to the keys of `MyOptions`. If it is, you give `options` the type `O`. If it doesn't, you can use `MyOptions` to trigger excess property checks as if you had wrote `options: MyOptions` the whole time.

```
function useMyHook<O extends MyOptions>(
    options: keyof O extends keyof MyOptions ? O : MyOptions
): MyReturnType<O> {
    return 42;
}
```

These will produce the same error:

```
useMyHook({
    foo: "bar", // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'foo' does not exist in type 'MyOptions'.
});

const options: MyOptions = {
    foo: "bar", // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'foo' does not exist in type 'MyOptions'.
};
```

While still allowing for objects that match `MyOptions`:

```
useMyHook({
    "42ms": true, // okay
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBLAtsAYtLAQ3gF44ADAEgG8A7AVywCNgoBfGgIk7gB85OWAM49+nEW3IBuAFBIUcALKIA8mBgYItIXDIAlYAGNoAEwA8mHPihEYAGjiFaiAHyy5yVMoMx6UWmieZiouunDUbO4AZvS0hhpacPRCwMoAEhAQANbBcKAwwLQmOspqCdouABQycLVwEOqa2gBccFnAiBBRcCp5IAVFOu2d3aWNWjoA-D1wrWPlQjIAlHOIPn4BQSHhNXVQwL7+cAAsAEyybDIyyamIGdmV1Lu1UZmtnEyEUJx2MmxL7mM2ngDQWqzKTR0ZCedTgrwg70+31+kSuN3SmSyj2eAjOwk4rRgUHowBRAJkQA)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
type MyOptions = {
  name: string,
  subName: string
}

type MyReturnType<O> = {
    objectName: O;
}

function useMyHook<O extends MyOptions>(options: O): MyReturnType<O> {
  // do something...
  options.name = 'overwritename';

  const result: MyReturnType<O> = {
    objectName: options
  }

  return result;
}

const options: MyOptions = {
   name: 'foo',
   subName: 'bar'
};

const optionsError = {
   name: 'foo',
};

useMyHook({ name: 'foo', subName: 'bar' });
useMyHook(options);

useMyHook({ name: 'foo' }); // This will error in
useMyHook(optionsError); // This will error
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyZgEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gLABQUU6AhgLYQBcUmwATsugOYA0JZmArgEYA5anQbNWbEgF8SJUJFggAShGC8m6ACrgIAHngA+XAW5koqfgCsIAY2DCa9eAG5ps4gDNe6O2nRReTAg4AAlUVABrfSgIAA9gCHQAE2w4RBQMTAMAClQkP0wnAEp6OBU1DW1IfSMiUigAegaoJNQGVBpgAAsJADp+0zyMrF7KGmMAclQANwgmAHcWBLGICddiUxtM4CgmCD4AG2BS5VV1LR0a4zqzcytbexF6IYLTGQ36vYr-PcPgdfeJC2WB2L0yJ3SBWupnITygEw84QmXHqDAEDlEE34FCYE2k6yB23M+UyAFEmExUExoaiVvQEUiUVICcRAsEQGFItl8LDHPDEahkWihHCsTiJlApEV1mzQuEIrkSVhpe5ZRz5dzeZiBRKpTKgnKuWCsOTKUwVR8gA)